# PHP Curl login to Tesco Mobile

Tags: php, curl, authentication

I am trying to login into Tesco Mobile, using PHP curl, I have the following code:

```
$postData='user=XXX&password=XXXXX';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://paymonthly.tescomobile.com/orderentry/LoginSubmit.do');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://paymonthly.tescomobile.com/orderentry/LoginSubmit.do');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);     
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

But have been unsuccessful, please can anyone help how I can achieve this. Please find the output from Live HTTP below:

Thanks in advance.

https://paymonthly.tescomobile.com/orderentry/LoginSubmit.do

> POST /orderentry/LoginSubmit.do HTTP/1.1 Host:
>   paymonthly.tescomobile.com User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel
>   Mac OS X 10.7; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0 Accept:
>   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>   Referer:
>   https://paymonthly.tescomobile.com/orderentry/LoginSubmit.do;jsessionid=60af415cd448d5728a9fa98cdf99
>   Cookie: JSESSIONID=60af415cd448d5728a9fa98cdf99;
>   reevoomark_marker=349049566;
>   reevoo_*utma=1.324660794.1360800582.1360800582.1360800582.1;
>   reevoo*_utmb=1.5.6.1360800582; reevoo_*utmc=1;
>   reevoo*_utmz=1.1360800582.1.1.utmgclid=CK6Vp5nBtLUCFeXKtAodVGIAVA|utmccn=(not%20set)|utmcmd=(not%20set)|utmctr=tescomobile;
>   reevoomark_bh_session=0af0a16fc00f5fbc8b0d28c571721a72;
>   CUSTOMER_UUID=04fdc3e6-59e1-4038-81b7-ec7c5d63c9d4;
>   __utma=152930744.490151867.1360800710.1360800710.1360800710.1; __utmb=152930744; __utmc=152930744; __utmz=152930744.1360800710.1.1.utmccn=(referral)|utmcsr=phone-shop.tesco.com|utmcct=/tesco-mobile/my-tesco-mobile/|utmcmd=referral
>   Connection: keep-alive Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   Content-Length: 32 user=dinoc83&password=c079378643 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   X-Powered-By: JSP/2.1 Server: Sun GlassFish Enterprise Server v2.1.1
>   Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8 Transfer-Encoding: chunked Date:
>
> ### Thu, 14 Feb 2013 00:15:27 GMT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checked form

Form attribute action have parameter  **jsessionid** In your code you don't use it. I think you should in first load page with form, then parse response code and get correct URL for post. And this need for initialize cookies.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change :
`$postData='user=XXX&password=XXXXX';`

by `$postData=array('user=XXX&password=XXXXX');`

There are some code samples in : http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Try to this in this way it's working for us posting data in another server

```
   $postData='user=XXX&password=XXXXX'
   $url ="https://paymonthly.tescomobile.com/orderentry/LoginSubmit.do";
   $ch = curl_init() or die(curl_error()); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postData); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);// here the request is sent to payment gateway 
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    $result=curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error());

    curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set `$postData` value this way:

```
$postData = array( 'user'=>'XXX', 'password'=>'XXXX' );
```

And note what:

> Passing an array to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS will encode the data as multipart/form-data, while passing a URL-encoded string will encode the data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded.